# the c++ primer exercise 13.13, about the constructor

Tags: c++

i did the exercise 13.13 of c++ primer, and here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct X{
X(){cout<<"X()"<<endl;}
X(const X&){cout<<"X(const X&)"<<endl;}
X& operator=(const X&){
    cout<<"X& operator=(const X&)"<<endl;
    return *this;
}
~X(){cout<<"~X()"<<endl;}
};

void foo(const X& cx, X bx){
vector<X> v;
v.push_back(cx);
v.push_back(bx);
}

int main(){
X* x1=new X;
X x2;
x2=*x1;
foo(*x1, x2);
delete x1;
return 0;
}
```

and I got the output which has four times of "X(const X&)", I guess the first three comes from passing x2, push_back(cx) and push_back(bx). but why there is the fourth "X(const X&)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with the way `push_back` is implemented.

One of the copies is due to passing `bx` to `foo` by value.
Make that parameter a reference, and the number of copies reduces by one.

The rest appear to all be due to `push_back`.
I tried your code at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php
with extra printouts before and after every `push_back`.
I also pushed a total of 10 elements onto the vector.
The second call to `push_back` caused the copy constructor to be called twice,
the third call caused it to be called three times,
the fifth call caused five times,
and the ninth call caused nine times.
All other calls to `push_back` caused the copy constructor to be called
only once.

But when I did `v.reserve(20)` before the first call to `push_back`,
every call to `push_back` resulted in exactly one call to the copy constructor.
When I changed the 20 to 8, the ninth `push_back` resulted in
nine calls to the copy constructor, all others resulted in just one call.

I conclude that the extra copy constructor calls are related to the
maintenance the `vector` has to do (copying existing elements)
when it grows without having "reserved" the space it requires.

So Michael Burr's hypothesis is correct, and you should be able to confirm
this too by experimenting with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly when the second element is added to the vector (the `v.push_back(bx);`) a resize of the vector's underlying storage is done and the single element already in the vector is copied to the new storage.

Add the following around the second `push_back()` call:

```
cout << "about to do push_back(bx)" << endl;
v.push_back(bx);
cout << "done push_back(bx)" << endl;
```